# Are there any limits of a file size when using "Map local"?

Tags: http, debugging, proxy, reverse-proxy, charles-proxy

I can't see all of the code when I use "Map local" in Charles. The file only displays 8000 characters for some reason...

My environment:
- OS: macOS Sierra
- Browser: Chrome
- File size of the file I would like to replace: 22.3KB

Answer (score 0):

Grab the source from the Chrome developer tool Network panel and save to a local file from there. The Charles preview is sometimes slow to load. Once you have the file saved locally go through the map local steps.